# Time and date generation webservice

Tags: c#, asmx

Can any one give me the code of web service (.asmx) for generating Time and date of a city, if I enter the name of a city in any part of the word..

Means in the web service consuming side..  say a Windows application I am reading the name of the city and I am sending it in to web service

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that anyone would just hand you the code for it, but you can write it yourself.

The hardest part is getting a list of all cities and what time zone they are in. Once you have identified the city and got it's time zone, the rest is easy:

```
DateTimeOffset time = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeSpan.Zero);
time = time.ToOffset(offsetOfTheCity);
```

Comment: i am a begginner,,i think that code is simple,,if any URL are available for adding webreference then fwd

Comment: What is it that you have problems with, really? Is it making the web service or using it?